# Syntax Error near the word "VALUES" In login page

Tags: c#, sql, database, authentication

i'm trying to create a login page for a Project site for school, but the problem is when im trying to open Login.aspx an error pops up in VS Express for web 2013 saying: http://prntscr.com/fjll5v

This is the CS file of the login page, but the line with the word Values seems fine:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string user_name = Request.Form["user_name"];
        string passwrd = Request.Form["passwrd"];

        string RegStatus;
        if ((user_name == "") || (passwrd == ""))
        {
            RegStatus = ("missing data or wrong data");
        }

        else
        {
            string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM YoadUserLists (user_name, passwrd) VALUES ('";
            selectQuery += user_name + "','" + passwrd + "')";
            Response.Write(selectQuery);
            MyAdoHelper.DoQuery(selectQuery);
            RegStatus = ("Login was succeessful");
        }
        Response.Write(RegStatus);
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

i don't understand what the problem is

Comment: Post the original code instead of images.

Comment: Posted the Original code as requested

Comment: You need to `Insert` statement not `Select`

Comment: I've tried as you said and i get this error:
"Incorrect syntax next '*'

Answer (score 1):

**STOP! HOLD! Don't use string concatenation for SQL statements. This will make your code vulnerable for SQL injection.**

Use this query with parameters (you are mistakenly making an insert instead of a select):

```
string selectQuery = "select * from YoadUserLists where user_name = @username and passwrd = @passwrd";
```

Add the parameters to your command like this:

```
var usernameParam = new SqlParameter("username");
usernameParam.Value = username;
command.Parameters.Add(usernameParam);

var passwrdParam = new SqlParameter("passwrd");
passwrdParam.Value = passwrd;
command.Parameters.Add(passwrdParam);
```

Comment: It won't be a public site just final project for school, bu thanks for the concern. when i tired ur code i get this : http://prntscr.com/fjloyk

Comment: Learn to use good practices *now*. Don't just start to use them 'when it is important'. Something not very important might become later...

Comment: when i used the code u provided i get this error: http://prntscr.com/fjloyk

Comment: i don't understand where do i add the code lines you mentioned in "add the parameters to your command like this..."

Comment: Probably you have to pass them to `MyAdoHelper.DoQuery(selectQuery);`.

Answer (score 0):

your SQL-Select seems to be a mix of an insert and select.
Because you say, that you want to make a Login i think you want to make a select.

May the required SQL-Request you want is:

```
SELECT user_name, passwrd FROM YoadUserLists WHERE ...?
```

Or do you want to make a Insert?

```
INSERT INTO YoadUserLists (user_name, passwrd) VALUES ...?
```

**Please notice, that your SQL is not protected against SQLInjections because you concat the given values directly into the SQL-Query without escaping!**

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed up some different things...
Your variable is named "selectQuery" and you also start writing `select * from ...` but then you continuing with the Syntax of an insert Statement.

With OleDbCommand it would work like the following:

```
...
using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
{
     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SOMETHING WHERE PARAMETER = ?";
     cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@PARAMETER", 1));
     ...
}
...
```

However, just concating a string for sqlstatements ist really bad and you should not do that.

I don`t know if this helps you, but if you want to perform a select to the database, then the Syntax of your Statement is wrong.

Comment: As shown above: If you want to select then: select * from somethine where columname = ...

Comment: so what is the correct syntax than? and forgive me for being stupid but what is the Command? where do i put it? i just need to fixed login code and explain what i did cwrong

Comment: There are a Million different ways to fire SQL Statements in C#. OleDbCommand is one of it. Please check out the MSDN reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2s5xd3s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: again i don't know how to use these i just don't get what's wrong with my Original Syntax

Comment: Do you want to insert something in the database or do you want to retreive data from it?

Comment: i to literally do a login page; use data from the Databse (registration is working) and just perform a simple act of "you logged in succesfully" or "you login failed" i don't really need a complete login just that^